# Как реализовать отправку и получение клиентом и сервером параметров с помощью Spring?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc

Хочу сделать сервер, на котором будут храниться данные студентов (оценки, номер зачетки, имя фамилия и тп). Для реализации использую *Spring*. Также делаю клиент для *Android*, в котором пользователь вводит данные, они отправляются на сервер, там проверяются.

Как отправлять данные на сервер? Код, написанный мной, ничего не возвращает.

**Сервер:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/students")
public class AtheniumController {

    private final AtheniumServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    public AtheniumController(AtheniumServiceImpl service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/student/{studentSurname}/{studentName}/{studentPatronymic}/{studentNumber}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String checkLogin(@PathVariable(value = "studentSurname") String studentSurname,
                             @PathVariable(value = "studentName") String studentName,
                             @PathVariable(value = "studentPatronymic") String studentPatronymic,
                             @PathVariable(value = "studentNumber") String studentNumber) {

        Student lvStudent = new Student(studentSurname, studentName, studentPatronymic, Long.valueOf(studentNumber));
        if (service.checkLogin(lvStudent)) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "Проверьте введенные данные! (Также возможна проблема в серверах ДГУ)";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "marks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Mark> getMarks() {
        return service.getMarks();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "marks/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        service.remove(id);
    }
}
```

**Android:**

```
public class RequestRegister extends AsyncTask<Student, Void, String> {
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Student... pStudents) {

        try {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(Constants.POST_STUDENT);
            } catch (MalformedURLException pE) {
                pE.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                assert url != null;
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException pE) {
                pE.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert urlConnection != null;
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

            jo.put("studentSurname", pStudents[0].getStudentSurname());
            jo.put("studentName", pStudents[0].getStudentName());
            jo.put("studentPatronymic", pStudents[0].getStudentPatronymic());
            jo.put("studentNumber", pStudents[0].getStudentNumber());

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(jo.toString().getBytes());

            String result = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.flush(); //очищает поток output-a
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        //return null;

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: что значит ничего не возвращает?  Приходит пустой ответ, приходит http ошибка, или на сервере exception?  Ps по какому урлу стучитесь на сервер?

Comment: Если через браузер пробовать, вбив ссылку - ошибка. Если через приложение - оно просто не грузит. Интерфейс тормозит, будто я прописал код в основном потоке и ничего не происходит.

Comment: какой url для подключения используете?

Comment: Локальный Ip-adress компа, на котором запущен Tomcat с этим сервером

Comment: напишите урл со всеми параметрами

Comment: в том вся суть, я не знаю как правильно это сделать. То есть вообще не знаю как отправить параметры. Сейчас решил спользовать другой метод, с помощью POST отправляю на сервер сущность, но реакция все та же

Comment: у вас в контроллере прописан маппинг метода- /student/{studentSurname}/{studentName}/{studentPatronymic}/{studentNumber} уберите / из маппинга, тогда путь должен выглядить так - <название хоста>:<порт>/students/student/{studentSurname}/{studentName}/{studentPatronymic}/{studentNumber}, вот. теперь вместо названий параметров пишите туда нужные значения и проверяйте, дергается метод, хотя бы с браузера. если тип не указан, то по дефолту это будет GET

Comment: не сработало. Все та же ошибка 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы замапили метод на `@PathVariable`, а отправляете `application/json` запрос. Чтобы получить Данные из `RequestBody` нужно аннотировать атрибуты метода контроллера через `@RequestParam` или предоставить POJO-объект, который будет автоматически заполнен данными из запроса.

Примерно будет выглядеть так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String checkLogin(@RequestParam(value = "studentSurname") String studentSurname,
                         @RequestParam(value = "studentName") String studentName,
                         @RequestParam(value = "studentPatronymic") String studentPatronymic,
                         @RequestParam(value = "studentNumber") String studentNumber) {

  Student lvStudent = new Student(studentSurname, studentName, studentPatronymic, Long.valueOf(studentNumber));
  if (service.checkLogin(lvStudent)) {
    return "OK";
  } else {
    return "Проверьте введенные данные! (Также возможна проблема в серверах ДГУ)";
  }
}
```

Но желательно использовать POJO и возвращать `ResponseEntity` с `HttpStatus`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> checkLogin(Student student) {
  if (service.checkLogin(student)) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
  } else {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Проверьте введенные данные! (Также возможна проблема в серверах ДГУ)");
  }
}
```

В апогее вообще обрабатывать ошибки в сервисах и логике не в контроллере, а в `@ControllerAdvice` и `@ExceptionHandler`, но это уже совсем другая история.